# Find which users are working on the same JobID

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am pulling only the JobID column from each User Sheet in a Google spreadsheet. I want to query which Users are working on the same JobID. I need to also list the User's name as a Column of the query as that column is not present in each User Sheet, though the Sheet name is the User's name. Is there someway to do this using Google Query?
e.g.

```
JobID |  Count | Users using it                    |
----------------------------------------------------
1001  |   3    | alex, hubert, mark                |
1002  |   1    | mark                              |
1003  |   2    | sally, chaz, maha                 |
1004  |   1    | hubert                            |
1005  |   2    | maha, mark                        |
```

P.S:  Also, Sheets could be renamed to some other user. so needed something dynamic.

Here is the link to the [Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AoJEb4Z66byGVID7AO3u2hlsivfbezlP8DJOWLrXar0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: It'd be helpful to have the description of the input data as well, not just the output. Also, please share what you have tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @mshcruz sure. give me few minutes. i shall share a spreadsheet.

Comment: Approx. how many users might be there, I mean how many different google sheets would be there?

Comment: not more than 10-12, but the JobID's would be approx 6k to 10k. Just to be specific, need a Google Query not appscript.

Comment: Also, sheets could be renamed to some other user. so needed something dynamic.

Comment: Have you considered creating a sheet with the name of all the users as well? @sifar

Comment: @ale13 no. So if i add a sheet containing to show all users how do i collate all sheet names into this sheet? Will it be volatile enough that it shows changes to sheet names? And finally how do we construct the Query formula?

Comment: added sheet containing User names manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, I've got a single formula to return the JobIDs and the users.  But to include the count of the number of users, I had to add another column and formula.  See below:

[image]

The key formula, in D1, is as follows:

```
={"Job ID","Users (hidden)";
  ArrayFormula(trim(split(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(transpose(query(query({
     query({ Users!A$1 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$1 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$1 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$2 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$2 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$2 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$3 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$3 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$3 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$4 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$4 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$4 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$5 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$5 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$5 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$6 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$6 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$6 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0) },
     "select max(Col1) where Col2 <>'' group by Col1 pivot Col2",0)
     ,,99^99)),
     "♦️[0-9 ]+" , ", "),
     "(.*),", "$1"),
     "♥️",0)))}
```

This returns an array of JobID and users, comma delimited.  It also includes the header labels  To add in the count of users, in the format you show, I hid the users column, added a column where I counted the number of users, and then added a following column that replicated the hidden users column.  There are lots of other ways of doing this, if you prefer.

The next key issue is that the formula fails if it includes a user (a row in Users) who does not have a tab, WITH a JobID in it as data.  There are several ways around this. One is to extra tabs (twenty or whatever your max users will be), given them names like TEMP1, TEMP2, etc. and have one JobID as filler in each of them, with a value of 999999, or similar.  Then the main formula query could exclude records with that JobID.  This would mean each user query would always return at least one data row, for JobID 999999, and not fail. When you get a new user, you would just replace TEMP1 in the User tab with their real name, and rename the TEMP1 tab to their name.

There may be other error checking that could prevent this, but I found that stacking several queries gave me an error  if one query returned no rows.  Eg.:

```
{ query(indirect(Users!A$1 & "!A$2:A").........);
  query(indirect(Users!A$2 & "!A$2:A").........);
  query(indirect(Users!A$3 & "!A$2:A").........);
  query(indirect(Users!A$4 & "!A$2:A").........)   }
```

gave me an error if either `User!A2` was blank, **or** there was not a tab matching the name in cell `User!A2`, **or** the tab with that name had no data.

If you take those measures, then the main formula can be preset to handle twenty (or more) users.  The formula I've shown above is for the current six users, but I've tested it with more.  I'll provide the formula for twenty users at the bottom.

Formula for twenty users.  Each "user" have a name, or a dummy name placeholder, in Users, must have a tab with that name, and there must be at least one JobID value in each tab, or a dummy JobID, perhaps like 999999.

```
={"Job ID","Users (hidden)";
  ArrayFormula(trim(split(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(transpose(query(query({
     query({ Users!A$1 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$1 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$1 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$2 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$2 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$2 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$3 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$3 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$3 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$4 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$4 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$4 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$5 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$5 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$5 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$6 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$6 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$6 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$7 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$7 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$7 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$8 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$8 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$8 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$9 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$9 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$9 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$10 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$10 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$10 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$11 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$11 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$11 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$12 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$12 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$12 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$13 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$13 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$13 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$14 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$14 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$14 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$15 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$15 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$15 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$16 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$16 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$16 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$17 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$17 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$17 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$18 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$18 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$18 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$19 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$19 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$19 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0);
     query({ Users!A$20 & "♦️" & row(indirect(Users!A$20 & "!A$2:A")), indirect(Users!A$20 & "!A$2:A")&"♥️"}, "where Col2<> '♥️'",0) },
     "select max(Col1) where Col2 <>'' group by Col1 pivot Col2",0)
     ,,99^99)),
     "♦️[0-9 ]+" , ", "),
     "(.*),", "$1"),
     "♥️",0)))}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very good. I will go ahead and mark your solution as an Answer for now. But wish there was an easier `Query` way to achieve this (even if it involved nested queries), instead of resorting to formulae. Another wish would be that Google could have included the Sheet name in the `CELL function (like in Excel)` or made available some Array functions for e.g. `SheetNames()` or `SheetIndexes()` that could be used to refer to the Sheets.

Comment: Hello @sifar, you can request this feature through `Help > Help Sheets improve` from the Sheet window.

Comment: Thanks @Jescanellas. I will put in a request soon. DONE.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the following work?
It dynamically pulls the sheet names to "query" from the User tab.  I think you would also want to first remove the Report and User names from that User tab.

This goes in C2 of Report, and currently needs to be dragged down.  I'll see if I can come up with an arrayformula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,
 {IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(USERS!A$1 & "!A$2:A"),A2),USERS!A$1,""), 
  IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(USERS!A$2 & "!A$2:A"),A2),USERS!A$2,""),
  IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(USERS!A$3 & "!A$2:A"),A2),USERS!A$3,""),
  IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(USERS!A$4 & "!A$2:A"),A2),USERS!A$4,""),
  IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(USERS!A$5 & "!A$2:A"),A2),USERS!A$5,""),
  IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(USERS!A$6 & "!A$2:A"),A2),USERS!A$6,"") })
```

I've only allowed for six users, but this could be extended to handle your ten to twenty, with an IF or IFERROR test to avoid issues if you have fewer users in the User tab at any time.

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

**UPDATE#1**
Following is the formula extended to allow for 20 users.  As long as they are added anywhere in Users!A1:A20, and they have a sheet name matching their listed name, their values will be included.  Let me know if you find any issues.  And I'll still try to see if it can be turned into an arrayformula.

```
=textjoin(", ",1,
 {if(countif(indirect(Users!A$1 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$1,""), 
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$2 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$2,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$3 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$3,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$4 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$4,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$5 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$5,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$6 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$6,""), 
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$7 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$7,""), 
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$8 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$8,""), 
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$9 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$9,""), 
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$10 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$10,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$11 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$11,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$12 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$12,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$13 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$13,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$14 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$14,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$15 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$15,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$16 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$16,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$17 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$17,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$18 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$18,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$19 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$19,""),
  if(countif(indirect(Users!A$20 & "!A$2:A"),A2),Users!A$20,"")})
```

Comment: this is interesting. But can it be incorporated as a query? Also, right now, the users are manually hardcoded by me in User's sheet. what if some sheet names are changed? Any ideas how to handle that? Also, since the JobID's are 6k to 10k, then an arrayformula with query solution would be the need.

Comment: Did you try replacing a user with a new user, and changing a sheet name?  This should work.  If you remove "USER" and "REPORTS" from being listed on the user tab, my formula cana be extended to handle 20 or more users.  I'm not quite clear why you feel a need for a query - can you explain?  And yes, an arrayformula would be nice.  But extending the formula all the way to the bottom of 10k rows can be done very easily, whether there are JobIDs down that far or not, so even that is possible, is it not?

Comment: Query for the sole reason because i have multiple rows and i need to join this query as a subquery with some other query on a larger dataset.

Comment: I have an idea for a query, but can't do it now - will try later today.